# Trying to run Apache, but VMWare Workstation is blocking port 80

Tags: apache-http-server, port, vmware-workstation

When I run Apache server it shows port 80 is busy because WMware Workstation is blocking it. How can I run Apache?

Comment: What version of VMware Workstation? What OS are you running VMware workstation on?

Comment: Are you trying to run Apache server on the host or virtual machine? Are you using NAT or bridged network for the virtual machine?

Comment: @uther version 8.0 running ubuntu

Comment: @erikxiv im running apache server on host and yes using NAT for the virtual machine

Answer (score 11):

From a VMWare [Knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005585)

### Connecting to shared virtual machines

Connection to VMware Workstation Server (the shared virtual machines) is administered by the VMware Host Agent service. The service uses TCP ports 80 and 443. This service is also used by other VMware products, including VMware Server and vSphere, and provides additional capabilities.

### Configuring shared virtual machines

With the Shared VMs Workstation preferences, you can disable/enable the server, assign a different port for connecting, and change the Shared VMs directory.

To access the Shared VMs Workstation preferences:

- Go to Edit > Preferences.
- Click the Shared VMs tab.

Comment: This should be the accepted answers. Helps me!

Answer (score 3):

VMWAare generally blocks port 443 for sharing between remote systems. This could block apache on xampp. To resolve this,

open VMWare,
Go to Edit > Preferences.
Click the Shared VMs.

DISABLE SHARING and this would mean port 443 is closed for access by VMWare and your apache on Xampp will run fine!